# Holding values of the search after refreshing the page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have asked this question, I didn't get my answer. So I did much more researches about this and still couldn't find a proper good answer for this.

My controller (shortened):

```
public ActionResult SearchResult(String sortOrder, String carMake, String carModel)
    {
        var cars = from d in db.Cars
                    select d;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(carMake))
        {
            if (!carMake.Equals("All Makes"))
            {
                cars = cars.Where(x => x.Make == carMake);
            }
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(carModel))
        {
            if (!carModel.Equals("All Models"))
            {
                cars = cars.Where(x => x.Model == carModel);
            }
        }
        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "Model":
                cars = cars.OrderBy(s => s.Model);
                break;
            default:
                cars = cars.OrderBy(s => s.Make);
                break;
        }

        return View(cars);
}
```

My Index view (shortened - this is where user filters cars by different inputs):

```
@model IEnumerable<Cars.Models.Car>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchResult", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
<label>Make</label>
<select id="MakeID" name="carMake">
    <option>All Makes</option>
</select>

<label>Model</label>
<select id="ModelID" name="carModel">
    <option>All Models</option>
</select>

<button type="submit" name="submit" value="search" id="SubmitID">Search</button>
}
```

My SearchResult view where shows the search results (shortened):

```
@model IEnumerable<Cars.Models.Car>

<table>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Make:</label>
            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Make)</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>Model:</label>
            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Model)</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>

<a href="@Url.Action("SearchResult", "Home", new { sortOrder= "Model"})">Model</a>
```

- My goal: When user clicks on the sort by Model the page will sort the results by Model.
- Problem: When the sortby is clicked, all the parameters of action `SearchResult` will be null since the search value do not exist in SearchResult View.
- Question: How to fix this?

Thanks, Amin

UPDATE: Any example would be deeply appreciated. I'm stuck with back-end the whole process of sending and fetching data between controller and view.

Comment: are you doing http post in your SearchResult

Comment: No sir, it has no [HttpPost].

Comment: well that the problem you are having you are pssing the sortOrder= "Model" in your action but all other values are null

Comment: So how would I fix this? Would you write the code for me please? I'm a little confused and trying to learn ASP.NET so I'm new with it.

Comment: This is the change I made, which I think is what you asked me to do: `public ActionResult SearchResult(String sortOrder)
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SearchResult(String carMake, String carModel){...}`

Comment: But still it gives error of course because the @foreach() in my view is expecting a list to go through.. so it gives me `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: the problem you are having is you are passing one parameter String sortOrder if you do somethink like <a href="@Url.Action("SearchResult", "Home", new { sortOrder= "Model", carMake="yourcarmake",  carModel="yourcarmodel"})">Model</a> it probably gone work but in your case it not clear how to know what values yourcarmake",  "yourcarmodel" supose to be

Answer (score 0):

You can create one class like below

```
    public CarFilter CarFilter;
    public byte PageSize;
    public short PageNumber;
    public int TotalRows;
```

where CarFilter is another class where you can store your filters enter by users.
and use this class as a model for your view.so that when you view is loading you can load car filter data.

Comment: This seems to work. However, I have issues implementing the back-end. Would you give an example please? I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can retain your search filters by doing any of the following:

1. Use sessions to store the filters on your search result view. This way, when you post on the same view using Sort you would still have the search filters.
2. (I prefer this one) Wrap your model in a class that has properties for your search filters. This way, you will still be able to retrieve the search filters. Provided that you have a POST for SearchResult that accepts the Wrapper Model as parameter.

Comment: Keep in mind using the session object in MVC can completely stop other ajax request processing until the current request finishes. The impact at times can be severe if doing parallel managed requests.

Comment: Could you give me an example please? I'm having difficulties in data types. and the wrapping model class is not being filled.

Answer (score 0):

Create Classes as follow:

```
class ManageCarSearch
{
    public CarFilter CarFilter;
    public byte PageSize;
    public short PageNumber;
    public int TotalRows;
    public String sortOrder;

}

Class CarFilter 
{
    public String carMake, 
    public String carModel

}
```

your searchResult view look like below:

```
@model IEnumerable<car>

<table>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Make:</label>
            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Make)</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>Model:</label>
            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Model)</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>

<a href="@Url.Action("SearchResult", "Home", new { sortOrder= "Model"})">Model</a>
```

and controller as below:

```
public ActionResult SearchResult(String sortOrder, String carMake, String carModel)
    {

        var cars = from d in db.Cars
                    select d;
        ManageCarSearch objsearch = new ManageCarSearch();
       ////your Logic

        return View(objsearch);
}
```

and you serach view look like below:

```
@model IEnumerable<ManageCarSearch>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchResult", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
<label>Make</label>
<select id="MakeID" name="carMake">
    <option>All Makes</option>
</select>

<label>Model</label>
<select id="ModelID" name="carModel">
    <option>All Models</option>
</select>

<button type="submit" name="submit" value="search" id="SubmitID">Search</button>
}
```

Comment: `ManageCarSearch` should be of type `IEnumberable<ManageCarSearch>`. And I think I should involve my database table in `ManageCarSearch` model class, isn't it?

Comment: And when I create a `ManageCarSearch objsearch = new ManageCarSearch();`. the next time the method is being called for sorting, it would create another objsearch which will replace the previous one, so I won't have access to searched values again.

Comment: its just the overview ... yes you can involve you database table in ManageCarSearch table.....

Comment: ManageCarSearch object you have to pass from view to controller on every request.

Comment: That's exactly where I do not know what to do! I know it's very silly to ask this, but how can I send ManageCarSearch object to my controller?